# Angularjs form submition with post and catching response , redirecting different view or displaying response on the same the view

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I am  trying to use $http.post and want display the response in the same view or different view by using ng-show directive.
    Control is coming to success and displaying divsion and immediatly disappearing. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('registrationApp', [ 'ngRoute' ]);

// create angular controller
myapp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

 $scope.regStatus =false;
 // function to submit the form after all validation has
 // occurred
 $scope.submitForm = function() {
  

  user = {       
   "type" : "admin",
   "emailid" : $scope.user.email,
   
  };
  var res = $http.post('/fosiness-web/services/user/registeruser', user);
       
  res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   alert("Success : " + JSON.stringify({
    data : data }));
   debugger;
   $scope.mydata = data;
   $scope.regStatus = true;
  });
  res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
    data : data
   }));
  });

 }

});
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color: #E8E8E8;"
  ng-app="registrationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  ...................
     <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="regStatus">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a> Success  <strong ng-                 model="user.message.description">{{mydata}}  {{regStatus}}</strong>
   </div>
  
  
<form id="registrationForm" method="post" method="POST"
      novalidate
     class="form-horizontal registerForm"
     data-bv-feedbackicons-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
     data-bv-feedbackicons-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
     data-bv-feedbackicons-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">
  
                       <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email-Id</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"
        ng-model="user.email" data-bv-notempty="true"
        data-bv-notempty-message="The email address is required and cannot be empty"
        data-bv-emailaddress="true"
        data-bv-emailaddress-message="The email address is not a valid" />
      </div>
                      ......................

                   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
       <!-- Do NOT use name="submit" or id="submit" for the Submit button -->
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"
        ng-click="submitForm()">Sign up</button>
       <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: provide a plunker of relevant code

Comment: angular side looks ok so I guess the issue is with CSS used, maybe it has some animation? Other thing is, you should not assign properties directly on the $scope ($scope.mydata , $scope.regStatus ) but rather define view model class that contains these properties, put it into $scope and work on it (like $scope.vm.mydata, $scope.vm.regstatus) - see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes for the explanation.

Comment: Hi @yiiframe here is the plunker link :   [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/THoUhwTSXQWMXfynhiY4?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you @ŁukaszZwierko for your suggestion.My problem is $scope values are getting updating, after request is over form is getting reload and values are not displaying. Plz let me know is any thing is required, i am working with this from last 2 days.